# Switching manually between tabs in personal msteams application

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have two tabs in my personal msteams application and I would like to navigate between them dynamically. Is it possible? I've tried to use `microsoftTeams.getTabInstances` method from msteams SDK to get my tabs and after that navigate to the chosen tab by invoking `microsoftTeams.navigateToTab` but this approach doesn't work - I get null from `microsoftTeams.getTabInstances`. My user is logged in (I've read somewhere that user must be logged in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried exactly this action, but I believe you should be able to do what you're trying using [Deep Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links). In particular, see the [Deep linking from your tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) where it talks about

> This is useful if your tab needs to link to [...] another tab [...]

and the syntax is

```
microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink(/*deepLink*/);
```

Just a reminder that in deep link syntax, e.g. `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>`, the appid is your Teams app id, and the "entityId" must match the "entityId" for your tab in your Teams manifest file.

Comment: Piotr, was this able to help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can deeplink to content in Teams from your tab. This is useful if your tab needs to link to other content in Teams such as to a channel, message, another tab or even to open a scheduling dialog. To trigger a deeplink from your tab you should call:

```
   var encodedWebUrl = encodeURI('https://tasklist.example.com/123/456&label=Task 456');
var encodedContext = encodeURI('{"subEntityId": "task456"}');
var taskItemUrl = 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fee194/tasklist123?webUrl=' + encodedWebUrl + '&context=' + encodedContext;
```

Please take a look [Deep Link to your tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-your-tab)

Comment: Why does the microsoftTeams.navigateToTab not work?